# Handling $resource with AngularJS and MVC.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, angularjs-resource

I'm using an AngularJS $resource to contact MVC ActionMethods on the server. The resource URL is /api/customer, so for the $resource.query function I provide an ActionMethod called Customer on the ApiController. This works fine.
Now I want to provide an ActionMethod for $resource.save.
Obviously, the 2nd ActionMethod needs the same name, but since neither ActionMethod has any parameters this is not allowed.
What is the best practice for this situation? Should I stay away from server side MVC for AngularJS projects?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have found that I can use parameters to change the url so that it contains the name of the appropriate ActionMethod. However, I don't know if this is the ideal approach. It feels a little dirty to me.

Comment: Are you using Web API or not? It's a completely separate thing from MVC, you don't necessarily want to add a dependency to it just to solve a problem that could quite easily be done with MVC alone. I guess more generally: do you really want to expose an API, or are you just doing it so you can use Angular?

Comment: I wasn't using WebAPI when I asked the question but I am now and it solves my problem (see next answer and comments). I think I could do it in ASP.NET MVC by deriving from ApiController and setting up some ApiRoutes but I haven't confirmed that. Yes, this is just so I can use AngularJS, specifically to create a single page app. If there is an ideal recommendation for this I'd still like to hear it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create a controller CustomerController deriving from ApiController. Then the methods

`Get(int id)` works for getting customer  with specific id. Url: `api/customer/1`

`Delete(int id)` works for deleting customer with specific id. Url: `api/customer/1`

Comment: This doesn't work. I just get 404 Not Found for all requests.

Comment: The 404 can come due to many reasons, such as routes not setup correctly. Current http method not passed. Look at some documentation around WebAPI and some samples. See how they setup their controller and routes.

Comment: After more research I found you are correct. Creating a WebAPI project provides the necessary controllers and routes but they can be manually added to an MVC project if you know how.

Answer (score 3):

Further to my comment, I am adding this answer in case someone finds it helpful. It solves my original problem but I don't know if it's the best solution.

Original factory:

```
app.factory("customerResource", function ($resource) {
    var customerResource = $resource("/api/customer/:id", { id: "@id" });
    return customerResource;
});
```

Original line in controller:

```
$scope.customers = customerResource.query();
```

Amended factory:

```
app.factory("customerResource", function ($resource) {
    var customerResource = $resource("/api/:action/:id", { id: "@id", action: "@action" });
    return customerResource;
});
```

Amended line in controller:

```
$scope.customers = customerResource.query({action: "get");
```

Now I can use other $resource functions using a different action, like so:

```
drawing.$remove({action: "delete"});
```

These calls will reach the `Get` and `Delete` ActionMethods on the ASP.MVC server.